# Creating items by POSTing a collection in a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest

I am trying to learn about REST principles by designing an API and am trying to follow the principles of REST as best I can. A very common practice in a REST API is to create a resource through a POST like this:

```
{
    "address_1": "123 Main St.",
    "city": "Anywhere",
    "some": "more stuff"
}
```

To create the address, you just `POST` it to: `/api/customers/ABC123/addresses`

...and get back something like:

`201 Created`
`Location: /api/customers/ABC123/addresses/XYZ789`

I think that's pretty clear. What about a situation, however, when you want to create multiple addresses at once, such as:

```
[
   {
      "address_1":"123 Main St.",
      "city":"Anywhere",
      "some":"more stuff"
   },
   {
      "address_1":"456 State St.",
      "city":"Somewhere",
      "some":"more stuff"
   }
]
```

In this case, I would still post to `/api/customers/ABC123/addresses`, however, I can't return a location to a resource, because multiple were created. However, I suppose could return the location of the collection, such as:

`201 Created`
`Location: /api/customers/ABC123/addresses`

However, in my own experience consuming APIs, it seems I encounter creation of a single item only (as in my first example) and not the creation of multiple items in a single POST (as in my second example). So, my question is:

Is the second example a bad practice? If so, why? It seems that allowing the creation of multiple items in a single POST would be convenient and reduce chatter.

If the second example is ***not*** a bad practice, is it appropriate to return the Location as I have shown in the second example?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you describe above, you are essentially modifying the customer resource by adding additional addresses. You've also added a constraint in that you want to be able to add multiple addresses at once.

Let's embrace the requirement.

So what do you do? As with most software problems. There isn't necessarily one best solution. Here are a few options...

You can update the entire customer e.g. `PUT` `/api/customers/ABC123`. Perhaps, the client first `GET`s the customer, then you add the new adddresses to addresses property, and finally PUT it back to the server. The operation returns `200` (no need to return `201` with location as you just invoked the location you would return). Also, remember that with REST, `PUT` must be idempotent, so invoking it over and over should always produce the same result.

Similarly, (and admittedly a little strange) if customer resources are for some reason super massive, you could perform a `PUT` operation at `/api/customers/ABC123/addresses` with the entire new list and again return `200` (again, no need to return the location as you just invoked it).

Now suppose things get really hairy and a `GET` on customer followed by a PUT just can't work (for whatever the crazy reason). You are given the requirement that says you must provide some way to modify the address list by providing just the new addresses. Here, `PUT` doesn't fit as it would not be idempotent. `POST` however does not have the requirement of idempotence, thus, POST can make sense. But what location do you return in the Location header? It doesn't make sense to randomly pick some item. It also doesn't make sense to return the location of all customer addresses. Well, luckily `POST` can provide an out. In this case, simply return status `200`. Still though, this '*smells*'. It doesn't feel RESTful. This is when you have to step back and realize, Hey, REST is great! But, its not a silver bullet. Sometimes things just don't fit perfectly. In situations like these, you did you best to find a RESTful way, but but sometimes, it just isn't there. In this case, you may need to provide a web service style endpoint for the piece of functionality.

- See this [blog](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/09/restful-design-principles/) post on RESTful Design Principles

Comment: Thank you for your pragmatic and thoughtful response - very helpful. Your referenced blog post was helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

The response is whatever you want to provide.

Your response might be an array or collection of locations, or a simple "success" or "failed" string, or  even an html table that you expect to be put inside a div by some javascript. You're building the API so you get to decide what the response should look like.

There are many tools that automatically turn functions into REST endpoints, so you might consider using one of those. A benefit is that you can return something, perhaps an array of strings, and it will automatically convert it to xml or json or yaml or whatever type was requested.